# How do I preview an image that is selected from a file input? (How do I detect when the user selects a file so I can preview the given image?)

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

So I'm trying to set up an image selection area, where the user selects an image, and the selected image is then previewed underneath the 'select an image' button. Here's my html:

```
<form action="#" id="submitImg">
    <!--Customize the file selection button-->
    <label for="myFile" id="chooseFileBtn"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Choose an Image</label><br>
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename" hidden>
    <!--<img> element where the selected image should appear-->
    <img src="#" id="imgPreview">
    <input type="submit" id="submitImage">
</form>
```

I've tried using a `input.addEventListener()`:

```
let chooseImg = document.getElementById('#myFile');
chooseImg.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  document.getElementById('imgPreview').src = document.getElementById('myFile').value;
}, false);
```

But it doesn't work, and inspect element says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`.

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IceAB.png)

I've also tried to use a `input.onchange`:

```
let chooseImg = document.getElementById('#myFile');
chooseImg.onchange = function(event) {
  document.getElementById('imgPreview').src = document.getElementById('myFile').value;
}
```

, but that didn't work either, and it gave a similar error message:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null`

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAwTG.png)

So how should I really go about this?

Answer (score 1):

vanilla JS dont use **#** character for **id**

change from

```
let chooseImg = document.getElementById('#myFile');
```

to

```
let chooseImg = document.getElementById('myFile');
```

Comment: I still get the same errors, and it still doesn't work right

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

```js
let chooseImg = document.getElementById('myFile'),
    img = document.getElementById('imgPreview'),
    finished = function(e)
    {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src); //clean up
    };

img.onload = finished;
img.onerror = finished;

chooseImg.addEventListener("change", function(e)
{
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
}, false);
```

```html
<form action="#" id="submitImg">
    <!--Customize the file selection button-->
    <label for="myFile" id="chooseFileBtn"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Choose an Image</label><br>
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename" hidden>
    <!--<img> element where the selected image should appear-->
    <img src="#" id="imgPreview">
    <input type="submit" id="submitImage">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use FileReader. You need create instance of FileReader, put function set src for image in event *onload* of that instance

```js
let chooseImg = document.getElementById('myFile');
chooseImg.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('myFile')

  readURL(fileInput)
  document.getElementById('imgPreview').src = document.getElementById('myFile').value;
}, false);

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      document.getElementById('imgPreview').src = e.target.result

    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" id="submitImg">
  <!--Customize the file selection button-->
  <label for="myFile" id="chooseFileBtn"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Choose an Image</label><br>
  <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename" hidden>
  <!--<img> element where the selected image should appear-->
  <img src="#" id="imgPreview">
  <input type="submit" id="submitImage">
</form>
```